# Application.worksheetFunction.match not working correctly VBA Excel

Tags: vba, function, excel, match

I am trying to generate a unique ID with a prefix. to so this I am generating a random number between 0000 and 9999 and adding that to the end of my prefix. What I want to then do is check the sheet in column A to see if that ID already exists and if so then it just generates another random number and it carries on till a unique one is found. To do this I am using a while loop. Below is my code. The issue that I am having is that once the match() functions does not find anything it the value remains as the last value ie: the row number that it found the last value. For example, if my id is T26 - 7055 it searches the sheet and finds that it already exists in row 59. it then generates another ID this time say T26 -2099 which does not exist, but the match function still returns 59 and the while loops just goes into infinite loop. I dont understand why this is happening and was hoping one of you guys would be able to help.

```
    Dim newID As String
Dim x As Integer
Dim matchedRow As Boolean

matchedRow = True
x = CInt(Int(9999 * Rnd()) + 1)
newID = "T26 - " & x
While matchedRow = True
    Dim match As Long
    On Error Resume Next
        match = Application.WorksheetFunction.match(newID, Sheets("Exceptions").Columns(1), 0)
   On Error GoTo 0
    If match <> 0 Then
        x = CInt(Int(9999 * Rnd()) + 1)
        newID = "T26 - " & x
        matchedRow = True

    Else
        matchedRow = False
    End If
Wend
```

Thanks

Comment: Move your `Dim match as long` up with the other Dim statements.  Reset match to 0 at the start of each loop - so just after your `While` line add `match = 0`.  
I'm sure there's a better way of creating unique ID's though.

Comment: This link may help:  http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/647784-excel-2010-generate-6-digit-unique-random-number-id-column.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not resetting `match` to 0 after you find a match.

After the line

```
matchedRow = True
```

put the line

```
match = 0
```

Having `Dim match as Long` at the start of the loop doesn't reset it.

Answer (score 2):

- Try renaming variable "match" to something else - Match is the name of the built-in Excel function
- Use Application.Match instead of WorksheetFunction.Match (there are subtle differences)

---

```
Dim newID As String
Dim found As Variant

Do

    newID = "T26 - " & CInt(Int(9999 * Rnd()) + 1)

    found = Application.Match(newID, Sheets("Exceptions").Columns(1), 0)

Loop While Not IsError(found)
```

Comment: Hi!
Could you explain what are these subtle differences between application.match and worksheetfunction.match?

Answer (score 1):

You are using Application.WorksheetFunction.match. This will throw an error if the match is not found and you have found a way around it. But this will also supress any legitimate errors that are found.

If you use Application.match you will we able to trap the error as follows:

```
Application.WorksheetFunction.IsError(Application.match(newID, Sheets("Exceptions").Columns(1), 0))
```

This will at least give you an idea of the error you are encountering.
Also: you are not using the exact match for your matching. I assume that, based on your story you will need that (this may be the cause for your troubles.
Just change the last 0 to a 1. You will get a more exact result.

```
Application.WorksheetFunction.IsError(Application.match(newID, Sheets("Exceptions").Columns(1), 1))
```

Comment: Thanks The only issue is that if I change the 0 to a 1 it incorrectly finds a value and goes back into an infinite loop. The 0 works fine